# Asignar un valor según el index de un array

Tags: javascript

Necesito extraer datos de un form con el valor de cada uno, según ello necesito que me haga una comparación y me asigne el item del array ya que el valor de los componentes tienen el mismo valor que el index del array, tengo este código.

```
const divisas1 = ["elige tu moneda", 1, 20.25, 3770, 0.86, 0.73];
let tipoMonedaOrigen2 = document.getElementById("selector2").value;
let valorMonedaOrigen2;

function calcular() {
  divisas1.forEach((item, index, arr) => {
    if (index == tipoMonedaOrigen2) {
      valorMonedaOrigen2 = item;
      console.log(valorMonedaOrigen2);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Pon un ejemplo que aclare lo que necesitas, no entiendo nada de lo explicas.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar indexOf e igualmente si pudieras aclarar mejor lo que necesitas exactamente

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp

```
const divisas1 = ["elige tu moneda", 1, 20.25, 3770, 0.86, 0.73];
const tipoMonedaOrigen2 = document.getElementById("selector2").value;
const valorMonedaOrigen2 = divisas1.indexOf(tipoMonedaOrigen2);

console.log(valorMonedaOrigen2)
```